# Position Submenu at the top of menu container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to build a menu like this one http://alizahid.github.io/slinky/ to use in a WordPress theme. I can't seem to align the submenu to the top, it always stays under the actual menu item.

Is there anyway to move a submenu from outside its parent and align it with the top of the whole menu instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code and what you've tried

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let say this is your build

```
<div id="patent">
<ul id="main">
    <li>
        <ul class="sup"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

let #parent position relative 
and main & sup position absolute

this will position the sup to the parent (in another word at the same place)

Comment: Thanks, got it working. A translate animation was messing it up.